# Place holder font changing when I am changing IsPassword value in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]I have an entry with hide/unhide image and customized font, which is used for password so by default I set it IsVisible to false. when user click on unhide image  I am showing making IsVisible to true. But When I can value the customized font for placeholder is changed to default font of the android but I dont want the default font. Please help me in this regard Thanks in advance.

My Code:
In xaml

```
             <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <CustomEntry:customEntry x:Name="entEmail" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Email / Phone number"  ReturnType="Next" Style="{StaticResource entFontStyleWhite}" />
                <CustomEntry:customEntry x:Name="entPassword" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Placeholder="Password"  IsPassword="True"  ReturnType="Done" Style="{StaticResource entFontStyleWhite}" />
                <Image x:Name="imgPassword" Source="eye_icon" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="Start">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="PasswordShow_Tapped" />
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
            </Grid>


    private void PasswordShow_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        entPassword.IsPassword = !entPassword.IsPassword;
        if(entPassword.IsPassword)
        {
            //visibile eye
            imgPassword.Source = "eye_icon";

        }
        else
        {
            //invisible eye
            imgPassword.Source = "home_eye_inactive_hide.png";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some example code, so we can see what you did until now and we can probably help you. If you have sensitive data, replace it with dummy data.

Comment: If forms can not do that , you can use `EntryRenderer` to custom Entry.

Comment: Thanks @Amel  and johnheaven would you please tell me how to do EntryRenderer for custom font

Comment: Handled by using event handlers and Reset the font family when I am changing the IsPassword property